# ValueError: invalid literal for float(): Timestep:

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a program that finds some data and runs a basic math function on the data, but when I run it I get the following error: `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): Timestep:`. The error occurs in line where I call `map(float,line.split()[1:])`.

Does anyone know why and how to fix this error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python


l=[]
with open("movie.xyz") as f:
   line = f.next()
   nat = int(line.split()[0])
   print nat
   f.next()# skip headers
   for line in f:
       if line.strip():
           l.append(map(float,line.split()[1:]))  # make all values floats   
#print l[0][0]
b = 0
a = 1
for b in range(55):
    for a in range(b+1,56):
    import operator
    import numpy as np
    #vector1 = l[b]
    vector1 = (l[b][0],l[b][1],l[b][2])
    vector2 = (l[a][0],l[a][1],l[a][2])
    #print('vector 1 = %' % vector1)
    #print('vector 1 = (%f,%f,%f)' % vector1)
    #print vector2
    x = vector1
    y = vector2
    vector3 = list(np.array(x) - np.array(y))
    #print vector3
    dotProduct = reduce( operator.add, map( operator.mul, vector3, vector3))    
    dp = dotProduct**.5
    print dp
```

first couple lines of data look like:

```
2805
Atoms. Timestep: 0
Cu 46.7176 27.1121 27.1121
Cu 43.2505 36.0618 32.4879
Cu 43.3392 36.0964 28.9236
Cu 43.2509 37.8362 27.1091
Cu 43.3406 36.0958 25.2957
Cu 43.2582 36.0629 21.737
Cu 43.2505 32.4879 36.0618
```

Comment: This means you're trying to convert something like `-`, `''` or `.` into a float. Can you post examples of what `line` in `f` is? Ideally a couple ones including the one where the code fails.

Comment: Some lines aren't only `float`, put a the `map` row within a `try` and see what you except and you'll probably figure it out.

Comment: Okay I added what the first couple of data points look like.

Comment: You can't convert `Atoms`, `Timestep`, `Cu` or anything like that into a float. You'll need to parse the string somehow. But yes, doing `try`...`catch` will work.

Comment: But I skip the first two lines where that is on... so that shouldn't bet he problem

Comment: The fact that 'Timestep:' is mentioned in the Traceback should be a giveaway that it _is_ the problem.

Comment: So is the problem that the first two lines aren't being skipped?

Answer (score 1):

insert

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

before this line and see what gives you `line.split()[1:]`

pdb = prompt debugger: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

or do this:

```
if line.strip():
    try:
        l.append(map(float,line.split()[1:]))  
    except ValueError:
        print "Value error at: ", line.split()[1:]
```

### #

to make this code work add this function:

```
def foo(value):
    try:
        result = float(value)
    except ValueError:
        print "cant parse %r into float" %value
        result = None
    return result
```

and replace the line:

```
l.append(map(float,line.split()[1:]))
```

to:

```
l.append(map(foo, line.split()[1:]))
```

Comment: I did the insert insert pdb; pdb.set_trace(), and I get the same error.

Comment: Then I got this :2805
> /nfs/mohr/bob/sam/vector_final(13)<module>()
-> l.append(map(float,line.split()[1:]))  # make all values floats
(Pdb)

Comment: You need to read little about pdb first, do this one with try and see what gives You.

Comment: when I do the try: e error at:  ['Timestep:', '70000']            
Value error at:  ['Timestep:', '71000']            
Value error at:  ['Timestep:', '72000']            
']

Comment: so You are trying convert `['Timestep:', '70000'] ` into float :)

Comment: So does that mean that my code isn't skipping over the first 2 lines? because thats the only place where timestep is

Comment: give a sample of that file content as a code, cant read this that way

Comment: Okay I added the sample data as a code that should be much easier to read.

Comment: if you enumerate in your looping of `f` you could see the line number where the error occurs or simply search for the location in the file with `Timestep: 70000`. The error is not from the header rows in your sample